# Number of AppDomain that an application has if it calls some COM object internally

Tags: .net

I created a .NET application and hosted it on IIS.

As per my understanding this application runs on one AppDomain. But the code in the application calls some COM objects.

Do these calls to COM execute within the same AppDomain, or will it run on some other AppDomain?

Can someone explain me how does the above scenario behaves?

Answer (score 0):

AppDomain is somewhat like a boundary for a web application hosted in an IIS server. Every Web application lives in its own AppDomain and has access to it's only resources. If there are 10 web application hosted on IIS, they will have 10 AppDomains respectively. One AppDomain cannot access the data of other.